# Error self.user.update_attribute undefined method nil:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara

**UPDATE POST** I'm noob in RoR and i start the test. I have an application and I try to use test with rspec and capybara, I want create user and test the login. But when i do my test i have some error with my models users, because in my app I create user and i call an after_create :create_order

I modify my factories.rb but i have an error in my update_attributes

See my model user.rb

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  has_many :ratings
  has_many :rated_sounds, :through => :ratings, :source => :sounds
  has_many :sounds ,:dependent => :destroy
  has_many :orders ,:dependent => :destroy
  has_many :song_ups ,:dependent => :destroy
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :registerable, :confirmable
  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me,
                  :nom, :prenom, :societe, :tel, :cgu, :sign_in_count, :trans_simu,
            :trans_limit, :project, :vat_number, :adress, :zip_code, :city, :tutorial

  after_create :create_order

 def create_order
  order = Order.create(user_id: self.id,files_left: 3)
  order.subscription =  Subscription.where(category: 'test').first || Subscription.create(category: 'test')
  self.update_attribute(:trans_limit, 1)

  #Ancien Order
 # Order.create(user_id: self.id, subscription_id: Subscription.where(category: 'test').first.id, files_left: 3)
  # self.update_attribute(:trans_limit, 1)
end

  def test?
    self.orders.trial.present? && self.orders.count==1
  end

  def unlimited?
    !self.test? && self.orders.current.where(time_left: -1).any?
  end

  def allow_send?
    !self.finish_order? && self.sounds.in_progress.count < self.trans_limit.to_i
  end

  def finish_order?
    self.orders.current.empty?
  end
end
```

For create my user in my test I use FactoryGirl. And i write this :

```
require 'factory_girl'

     FactoryGirl.define  do
          factory :user do
             sequence(:email) {|n| "email#{n}@factory.com" }
             password "foobar"
             password_confirmation "foobar"
             societe "RspecTest"
             prenom "John"
             nom "Doe"
             tel "0101010101"
             confirmed_at Time.now
             association :order
          end
          factory :order do
            association :subscription

          end
          factory :subscription do
          end
        end
```

And one of my test is :

```
scenario "User login right" do
    visit new_user_session_path
    current_path.should == "/users/sign_in"
    page.html.should include('<h2>Se connecter</h2>')
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    fill_in "Email", :with => user.email
    fill_in "Mot de passe", :with => user.password
    check "user_remember_me"
    click_button "Connexion"
    page.should have_content('Mon compte')
    current_path.should == root_path
  end
```

**My order.rb**

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :nb_files, :user_id, :period, :time_left, :subscription_id, :promo_id, :promo_end_date, :max_time_file, :files_left, :ended_at
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :subscription
  scope :current, where('files_left != ? AND time_left != ? AND (ended_at >= ? OR ended_at IS ?)', 0, 0, Time.now, nil)
  before_create :init_value

  def self.trial
    self.where(subscription_id: Subscription.where(category: 'test').first.id).first
  end

  def init_value
    self.time_left = self.subscription.trans_seconds
    self.max_time_file = self.subscription.max_time_file
    if self.subscription.category != 'test'
        self.user.update_attribute(:trans_limit, 1)
      Order.where(user_id: self.user_id, subscription_id: Subscription.where(category: 'test')).destroy_all
    else
      self.files_left = 3
    end
  end
end
```

**My error :**

```
Failure/Error: user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
NoMethodError:
undefined method `trans_seconds' for nil:NilClass
# ./app/models/order.rb:13:in `init_value'
# ./app/models/user.rb:21:in `create_order'
```

I hope you can help me. Thank's

Answer (score 1):

In `create_order` try using this:

```
Order.create!(user: self, subscription: Subscription.where(category: 'test').first, files_left: 3)
```

Use objects instead of plain ids.

#### On `before_*` methods

To make sure that validations pass, return `true` at the end of these methods. In your case, add `return true` at the end of the `init_value` method.

Comment: I try what you wrote and i have an other error :    ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error:
       Can't mass-assign protected attributes: user, subscription
     # ./app/models/user.rb:21:in `create_order'

Comment: Make sure that the `user` and `subscription` fields are available in the `Order` model. Eg. verify to have set `belongs_to :user` and `belongs_to :subscription` in `Order`

Comment: I have in my order model the belongs_to :subscription and the belongs_to :user ,  
 belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :subscription.

I can upload my Order model if you want.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Maybe an issue with the `return true` missing in a method.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have Subscription with category 'test' in your database. Solution depend on how you want to handle this kind of error.

If you expect this subscription always to be in your database, use db:seed rake task for prepopulating your db. (try googling it to find out how to do this)

If you don't want to assign any subscription if given doesn't exist try:

```
def create_order
  order = Order.create(user_id: self.id,files_left: 3)
  order.subscription =  Subscription.where(category: 'test').first
  self.update_attribute(:trans_limit, 1)
end
```

And finally, if you want to create such a subscription if it doesn't exist:

```
def create_order
  order = Order.create(user_id: self.id,files_left: 3)
  order.subscription =  Subscription.find_or_create_by_category('test')
  self.update_attribute(:trans_limit, 1)
end
```

Comment: Ok , I try your second choice, and I understand my problem but now I have an other problem in my test : 
1) UserAction User login right
     Failure/Error: user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `trans_seconds' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/models/order.rb:13:in `init_value'
     # ./app/models/user.rb:21:in `create_order'
     # ./spec/features/user_connection_spec.rb:39:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

I Upload my order.rb

Comment: Every time you see error `'foo' undefined for nil:NilClass` it means you're having nil where you don't expect it. In this case in first line of your init_value methods, self.subscription is nil, as it is not created by your factory.

Comment: Ok , so I need add the subscription in my user factory ? Like this :
subscription "test"  ? Or no , I need create new factory ? because subscription is use for create order and order is for user.

Comment: You should read about factories here: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md. There is a really nice chapter on creating associated objects.

Comment: I edit my post but I have the error in my update_attribute , i dont know why. Can you help ?